# Unit testing CSV parsing logic

Tags: csv, rust

I'm using the [CSV crate](https://crates.io/crates/csv) to read CSV files.  I then parse the content.  I would like to unit test the parsing logic.  Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut rdr = csv::ReaderBuilder::new()
        .from_path("test.csv")?;

    process(rdr.records());

    Ok(())
}

fn process(iter: StringRecordsIter<File>) -> Result<String, String> {
    for result in iter {
        // Parsing takes place here
        println!("{:?}", result);
    }
    //  Post-parsing using entire file content takes place here
    Ok(String::from("My Result Here"))
}
```

In my unit test I would like to be able to construct sequences of `StringRecord` objects, pass them to the `process()` method and validate the results.  I can successfully create a `StringRecord` using the simple `StringRecord::new()` and fill it with values using `record.push_field("my field value")`.  However, I'm struggling to create an iterator that returns my values to pass to the `process()`.  Any suggestions?  I'm happy to change the arguments to `process()` if this makes things easier.

Comment: You can make `process` into a generic: `fn process (iter: impl Iterator<Item = csv::Result<StringRecord>>) -> Result<String, String>`. Then you can call it with whatever `Iterator` your test harness can create as well as with the `StringRecordsIterator` used in production.

Comment: Thanks @Jmb.  Your solution works nicely.  I've added the details of the test and posted it as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion made by Jmb to change the signature of `process()` to `fn process(iter: impl Iterator<Item = csv::Result<StringRecord>>) -> Result<String, String>` works nicely.

Here's the solution in detail.  Firstly the only change to `process()` is to make it accept more types:

```
fn process(iter: impl Iterator<Item = csv::Result<StringRecord>>) -> Result<String, String> {
    for result in iter {
        // Parsing takes place here
        println!("{:?}", result);
    }
    //  Post-parsing using entire file content takes place here
    Ok(String::from("My Result Here"))
}
```

The `main()` remains identical as `rdr.records` can still be passed to `process()`.  Then the testing looks like this:

```
#[test]
fn my_test() -> Result<(), String> {
    let record1 = result_record(&["Value 1", "Value 2"]);
    let record2 = result_record(&["Value 3", "Value 4"]);
    let records = vec![record1, record2];
    let result = process(records.into_iter())?;
    assert_eq!("My Result Here", result);
    Ok(())
}

fn result_record(fields: &[&str]) -> csv::Result<StringRecord> {
    let mut record = StringRecord::new();
    for field in fields {
        record.push_field(field);
    }
    Ok(record)
}
```